# Accessing a variable by 3 threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that has three threads and a hashmap that stores data. One of the threads writes data to hashmap and two other read it. Something like this:

```
public static class collector{
  Thread writter;
  Thread reader1;
  Thread reader2;
  HashMap storage;
  ...
  public void write(String s){
    storage.put(s.hashcode(),s);
  }
  public String read(long hash){
    return storage.get(hash);
  }
  public Set readAll(){
    return storage.entrySet();
  }
}
```

I want the first thread (writer) to run the first method (write), and reader1 run read and reader 2 run readAll. But I couldn't find anyway to access storage in threads (run method). How can I write threads to run like these 3 methods while they all have access to storage at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class is static you can simply call collector.write from thread's run method.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Look at the Java docs about what a "static" class actually means -- it has nothing to do with "static" variables or "static" methods, which is what you are thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to make this class thread-safe, you should use a thread-safe hash map implementation, like `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` rather than plain old `java.util.HashMap`.

Another poster suggested holding a `collector` instance in a singleton, which is equivalent to a global variable. Rather than using global data, I would pass a `collector` instance into each thread. You can define a subclass of `Runnable` which takes a `collector` instance as an argument to its constructor. Store the `collector` in an instance variable. Then use it from within the `run()` method. When you start your threads, give a different `Runnable` object to each one (using the appropriate `Thread` constructor).

Something like:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {
  private collector myCollector;
  public MyTask(collector _myCollector) {
    myCollector = _myCollector;
  }
  public void run() {
    // do something with myCollector
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't need to be safe. because one of them just writes into the hashmap. the other 2 read it. my problem is that when I want to define a thread (`implements runnable`) in `collector` class I couldn't reach `storage`. how can I access to `storage` hashmap.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you edit that.
How can I define an instance variable?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be thread-safe. Believe me. If you don't make it thread-safe, it may work most of the time, but it is possible that it may fail sometimes. (For example, when you add data to a `HashMap`, it may need to expand the storage used internally by the Map. If a reader is trying to traverse the structure as it is being expanded, you could get a `NullPointerException` or something similar.)

Comment: I just added some sample code. It's not tested, guaranteed-working code -- just something to give you an idea.

Comment: OK, if in `run()` I change `myCollector`, would the original variable that is passed to this thread changes?

Comment: If you execute `myCollector = ...;`, i.e. reset `myCollector` to point to a different object, then the original object, which will still be referenced by the other threads, will be unchanged. If you execute `myCollector.write()`, then naturally the other threads will see the change (since they are all referencing the same object).

Comment: Are you learning Java right now? I suggest you study the idea of objects and object references more carefully and build up your understanding of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Write a singleton class with that variable and write, read, readAll methods. See that you synchronize on the `storage` object or synchronize the methods. Access this singleton class from the three threads.